# Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia Driver Crashin When Disabling Built-In Display

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am working on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 3 with Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.14.0-1027-oem) and Nvidia drivers 510.54.

I connect this laptop to two external displays through USB-C with a [wavlink](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DCLK55V) docking station and I'm observing a weird behavior: I want to disable the built-in display (so that I can close the laptop lid and use only the external displays) but when I do that the system freezes and the only option left is to press the laptop power button for some seconds in order to shut it down.

I have a certain feeling that this issue is caused by the Nvidia drivers because if in "Software Updates"->"Additional Drivers" I choose the nouveau ones this does not happen. In case you are wondering I am bound to use the Nvidia drivers as I have to work with nvidia container runtime.

I tried to upgrade the Nvidia drivers following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076957/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-when-second-monitor-connected-by-hdmi) but nothing changed.

Do you have any idea of how I can fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same exact problem on a Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen 4, which has a lot of similarities with yours. It also started 2 days ago after running some Ubuntu updates. I am the Lenovo Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock, so I don't think it's the dock.

Unfortunately, I have not found a solution. Rolling back to earlier NVIDIA drivers isn't working and neither is reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04.4. It's a pretty serious problem and has made my laptop unusable with any external displays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gone. It looks like sometimes the Nvidia driver does not load correctly. If I re-install it through `software-properties-gtk` everything works again.